# ValueInjector Stack Overflow on mapping entities with parent entities

Tags: c#, mapping, valueinjecter

I am using ValueInjecter to handle mapping my POCO entities to my DTO entities. I have been using [Automapper Simulation](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Automapper%20Simulation&referringTitle=Home) as my main mapper. This allows me to simply write a mapping like this:

```
var entity = GetEntityFromDatabase();
var dto = Mapper.Map<Entity, EntityDTO>(entity);
```

This has been working great, until I needed to get entities from my database that have a parent-child relationship. The problem is that this code I have been using will recursively go through all properties. If I have a POCO that looks like this,

```
public class Entity {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Entity Parent {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Entity> Children {get; set;}
}
```

my code will bomb on the endless loop, trying to map the cyclic references. I would like to continue to use the Automapper Simulation source as my main mapper, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to fix my issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I solved it by changing the Automapper Simulation Mapper.cs file. I implemented a depth on the recursion and if I go over that depth, I set the object to an already created object. I'm sure this could be improved, but hey, it works for now!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

namespace MySystem.Services.Mapping
{
    // the static mapper class
    public static class Mapper
    {
        private static IList<ObjectContainer> _objects;

        //map source to an existing target
        public static TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target)
        {
            target = MapperFactory.GetMapper<TSource, TTarget>().Map(source, target);
            return target;
        }

        //create a new target and map source on it 
        public static TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
        {
            _objects = new List<ObjectContainer>();
            var target = (TTarget)Creator.Create(typeof(TTarget));
            var obj = MapperFactory.GetMapper<TSource, TTarget>().Map(source, target);
            _objects.Add(new ObjectContainer()
                             {
                                 original = source,
                                 converted = obj
                             });
            return obj;
        }

        public static object Map(object source, object target, Type sourceType, Type targetType)
        {
            target = target ?? Creator.Create(targetType);
            var getMapper = typeof(MapperFactory).GetMethod("GetMapper").MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, targetType);
            var mapper = getMapper.Invoke(null, null);
            var map = mapper.GetType().GetMethod("Map");
            var obj = map.Invoke(mapper, new[] { source, target });
            _objects.Add(new ObjectContainer()
                             {
                                 original = source,
                                 converted = obj
                             });
            return obj;
        }

        public static object MapFinal(object source, object target, Type sourceType, Type targetType)
        {
            foreach (var obj in _objects)
            {
                if (source.Equals(obj.original))
                {
                    return obj.converted;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ObjectContainer
    {
        public object original { get; set; }
        public object converted { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MapperFactory
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<Type, object> Mappers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public static ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget> GetMapper<TSource, TTarget>()
        {
            //if we have a specified TypeMapper for <TSource,Target> return it
            if (Mappers.ContainsKey(typeof(ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>)))
                return Mappers[typeof(ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>)] as ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>;

            //if both Source and Target types are Enumerables return new EnumerableTypeMapper<TSource,TTarget>()
            if (typeof(TSource).IsEnumerable() && typeof(TTarget).IsEnumerable())
            {
                return (ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumerableTypeMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), typeof(TTarget)));
            }

            //return the default TypeMapper
            return new TypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>();
        }

        public static void AddMapper<TS, TT>(ITypeMapper<TS, TT> o)
        {
            Mappers.Add(typeof(ITypeMapper<TS, TT>), o);
        }

        public static void ClearMappers()
        {
            Mappers.Clear();
        }
    }

    public interface ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>
    {
        TTarget Map(TSource source, TTarget target);
    }

    public class TypeMapper<TSource, TTarget> : ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>
    {
        public virtual TTarget Map(TSource source, TTarget target)
        {
            target.InjectFrom(source);
            target.InjectFrom<NullablesToNormal>(source);
            target.InjectFrom<NormalToNullables>(source);
            target.InjectFrom<IntToEnum>(source);
            target.InjectFrom<EnumToInt>(source);
            target.InjectFrom<MapperInjection>(source);

            return target;
        }
    }

    public class EnumerableTypeMapper<TSource, TTarget> : ITypeMapper<TSource, TTarget>
        where TSource : class
        where TTarget : class
    {
        public TTarget Map(TSource source, TTarget target)
        {
            if (source == null) return null;
            var targetArgumentType = typeof(TTarget).GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(targetArgumentType));
            var add = list.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

            foreach (var o in source as System.Collections.IEnumerable)
            {
                var t = Creator.Create(targetArgumentType);
                add.Invoke(list, new[] { Mapper.Map(o, t, o.GetType(), targetArgumentType) });
            }
            return (TTarget)list;
        }
    }

    public static class TypeExtensions
    {
        //returns true if type is IEnumerable<> or ICollection<>, IList<> ...
        public static bool IsEnumerable(this Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable)))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class Creator
    {
        public static object Create(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsEnumerable())
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
            }

            if (type.IsInterface)
                throw new Exception("don't know any implementation of this type: " + type.Name);

            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }

    public class MapperInjection : ConventionInjection
    {
        public const int MaxDepth = 20;
        public static int _depth = 0;

        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name &&
                !c.SourceProp.Type.IsValueType && c.SourceProp.Type != typeof(string) &&
                !c.SourceProp.Type.IsGenericType && !c.TargetProp.Type.IsGenericType
                ||
                 c.SourceProp.Type.IsEnumerable() &&
                   c.TargetProp.Type.IsEnumerable();
        }

        protected override object SetValue(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            if (c.SourceProp.Value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (_depth > MaxDepth)
                return Mapper.MapFinal(c.SourceProp.Value, c.TargetProp.Value, c.SourceProp.Type, c.TargetProp.Type);
            _depth++;
            object val = Mapper.Map(c.SourceProp.Value, c.TargetProp.Value, c.SourceProp.Type, c.TargetProp.Type);
            _depth--;
            return val;
        }
    }

    public class EnumToInt : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name &&
                c.SourceProp.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum)) && c.TargetProp.Type == typeof(int);
        }
    }

    public class IntToEnum : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name &&
                c.SourceProp.Type == typeof(int) && c.TargetProp.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum));
        }
    }

    //e.g. int? -> int
    public class NullablesToNormal : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name &&
                   Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(c.SourceProp.Type) == c.TargetProp.Type;
        }
    }

    //e.g. int -> int?
    public class NormalToNullables : ConventionInjection
    {


    protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
    {
        return c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name &&
               c.SourceProp.Type == Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(c.TargetProp.Type);
    }
}
```